# Как в С# парсить JSON и вытащить в массив строк значения body

Tags: c#, json, парсер, json.net

Пример ответа:

```
{"response":{"count":33,"unread":16,"items":[{"id":33,"body":"Текст 10","user_id":197651328,"from_id":197651328,"date":1508043287,"read_state":0,"out":0},{"id":32,"body":"Текст 9","user_id":197651328,"from_id":197651328,"date":1508043283,"read_state":0,"out":0}],"in_read":17,"out_read":33}}
```

Это обычный vkapi и метод messages.getHistory

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+json?sort=votes&pageSize=50  ничего не подходит?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data   вот вам пример.